# SSIS Data Flow for a Noob

Tags: oledb, dataflow, ssis

I'm still very new at programming, and our local SSIS genius isn't here today for me to pick his brain.

I am working on an existing SSIS package and am making modifications to a specific .dtsx file. The data flow has an OLE DB source, which I have successfully changed the sql query to fit my project specs. The Destination is a connection flat file, which I have modified the column mappings to fit the new query.

I have a few concerns:

1. The source connection originally used SQL Server Authentication, and I don't have the user name or password. I can use Windows Authentication to test it locally, but in the end it will be set up by someone else as a scheduled task on a server somewhere. (I realize this is probably a question for people at my work, but I figured I would fill you guys in).
2. The destination preview doesn't show anything. I can, however, successfully parse and preview the Source query...
3. I also don't understand what "Error Output" means on the Source Editor.
   [image: Source Editor Error Output] 
   Is this set up correctly already, or does it mean there will be some errors in the output?

   Any explanations or elaborations would be helpful, but my overall question is: "Am I missing something for this .dtsx, or is this project finished and ready to be set up as a scheduled task?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It will depend on the package configuration. usually user\password are read from a configuration mechanism (file or server)
2. Yes, it should be fine
3. It means what should the task do when it finds an error. It can fail the component or ignore the error for example

Comment: Excellent! So can this .dtsx be set up as a stand-alone scheduled task? Or do I need deliver a .exe file?

Comment: the dtsx file can run stand alone, you dont need an .exe You can set a job to run the package